# WebStorm uses Stylelint to lint markdown file incorrectly

Tags: frontend, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, stylelint

I just found WebStorm is using the Stylelint to lint the `README.md` file.

[image]

Here's my Stylelint config:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["stylelint-prettier"],
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-less",
    "stylelint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "customSyntax": "postcss-less",
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": true
  }
}
```

My WebStorm config is pretty simple:

[image]

WebStorm version: 2021.1.3

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug report and the supporter of the tool fixed the tool. There is no coding involved in this.

Answer (score 1):

this is fixed in 2021.3.1, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53407#focus=Comments-27-5581497.0-0
Please consider upgrading your IDE